# how to convert jpg to pdf in Android java

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to convert several .jpg files (taken using the device camera) to ONE .pdf file.
I saw a lot of tools like iText, mupdf, PDFjet, pdjBox.

Is there something more simple? (like an API ready for android?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using iText Library to convert the text to pdf. Use this to convert image to pdf.

```
import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;
public class imagesPDF
{     
    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception
    {                  
        Document document=new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("YourPDFHere.pdf"));
        document.open();
        Image image = Image.getInstance ("yourImageHere.jpg");
        document.add(new Paragraph("Your Heading for the Image Goes Here"));
        document.add(image);               
        document.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: and how do i add multiple images, each image in a seperate page..?

Comment: Hey @Nathan, I have used your code to convert .jpg file to pdf. But the problem is that I am getting only a part of my image in Pdf document while my image is fully stored in the device. Can you please help me with that.

Comment: its a bit urgent. If you can help. So I can accept your answer.